Django reverse ForeignKey returns None
I have Student and Mark models in different apps of one project.
# project/study
# models.py
class Mark(models.Model):
    ...
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        "students.Student",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="marks",
        related_query_name="mark",
    )


# project/students
# models.py
class Student(models.Model):
    ...

# views.py
class StudentDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Student.objects.prefetch_related("marks")
    template_name = "students/one_student.html"
    context_object_name = "student"


# one_student.html
...
    <p>{{ student.marks }}</p>
...

Output of html is "study.Mark.None" That is my problem.
I tried making ManyToOneRel field on student, select_related, making custom view func, but that does not help. Reverse ForeignKey brings None.
I watched related questions - can't understand answers, because they are unrelated directly to my situation.
I'm expecting to get all Student's marks.
What am I doing wrong?

We can use django model Prefetch like this:
from django.db.models import Prefetch
queryset = Student.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch("marks", queryset=Mark.objects.all(), to_attr="student_marks"))

In html template you have to iterate over the loop like this:
{% for mark in student.student_marks %}
    <p>{{ mark }}</p>
{% endfor %}


any hints how to limit prefetch queries, using Prefetch? If I want to get 3 last student's marks (for example)

Figured out, (you can just take slice of queryset)

In queryset, we can add order_by() if you have created_at or other field in model.

The related_name='marks'. Furthermore you here got the manager, not a queryset, use .all() [Django-doc] to get the objects:
<p>{{ student.marks.all }}</p>
You probably also should enumerate over it, like:
{% for mark in student.marks.all %}
    {{ mark.score }}
{% endfor %}

My brain just zapped on this one. I tried like marks_all, marks_set etc. Thx m8
